# Django set Initial data in Forms

Tags: django, forms, django-forms, django-views

I am new to Django, Let say I have a view like follow with form

```
class DepartmentCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    form_class = DepartmentForm
    template_name = os.path.join(TEMPLATE_FOLDER, "create/index.html")

    def get_success_url(self):
        position_id = self.kwargs.get('position_id')
        return reverse_lazy('departments_list', kwargs = { 'college_id' : 
        college_id })


    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super(DepartmentCreateView, self).get_initial()
        initial.update({ 'college' : self.kwargs.get('college_id'), 
        'code' : 1 })
         return initial
```

my form looks like

```
class DepartmentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Department
        fields = ('name', 'college', 'code')
```

when I display form I am setting some default values to some fields(college) using `get_initial()`, it works as expected, but when I submit the form if the form is invalid(for example code is required but value is null) it shows error message as expected in the code field, but form fails to set default value to college again.

what mistake i made here?

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what you want here. The normal behaviour for form validation across the web is to redisplay the errors along with the invalid data, not to reset the choice to the default.

Comment: I updated my question, please check.

Comment: Well like I say, you haven't made any mistake, that is the way things work. It would be very confusing for users if it worked differently.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `initial= your_value` for each field as found in [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/fields/#initial).
This should be in your forms.

OR

You can populate it key value pair like `initial= {'your_key', your_value}` when you init your form.

Answer (score 2):

you can override the `get_form` to set the value of the input to your initial value

```
def get_form(self, form_class=None):
    form = super(CreatePost, self).get_form(form_class)
    form.fields['your_input'].widget.attrs.update({'value': 'new_value'})
    return form
```

Answer (score 0):

Django have a method `get_initial_for_field` for form, and in your case correct write that:

```
def get_initial_for_field(self, field, field_name):
    """
       field_name: string = name of field in your model (college, code, name)
       field = class of this field
       return: value to initial, string, int or other (example: datetime.date.today())
    """

    if field_name == 'college':
        return self.kwargs.get('college_id')

    elif field_name == 'code':
        return '1'
```